# Оправдано ли использование Nginx как фронтенд сервера в моем проекте?

Tags: node.js, nginx, сервер, linux, javascript

У меня есть сайт одностраничник Nginx + Nodejs. Nginx отдает статику, а Нод обрабатывает любые другие запросы. Я читал, что это помогает разгрузить Нод.

**Но у меня из статики только index.html, один файл JS и один CSS.**

*Node отправляет клиенту JSON и изредка картинки.*

Будет ли существенная разница в производительности, если убрать Ngnix? Ведь у меня мало статики. **Имеет ли смысл использовать Ngnix?**

Comment: Экономия на спичках в масштабах целого леса.

Answer (score 1):

> Будет ли существенная разница в производительности, если убрать Ngnix?

зависит от посещаемости сайта и архитектуры приложения.

> Имеет ли смысл использовать Ngnix?

скорее да, чем нет.